# Delta Query should work for both these scnarios

Tags: microsoft-graph-api

I am tracking any changes in the EntraId user through [delta queries](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/graph/api/user-delta). Let's say user attributes are modified in two ways.

1. A user attribute is changed in the EntraID portal.
2. A user attribute is changed via Graph APIs.
   Will the changes in both these scenarios could be tracked via delta queries?

Answer (score 0):

I'm the PM for Delta Queries.

This should absolutely work regardless of where the state change originates.